# mysql php turkish character issues

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have these codes after database connection

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = 'UTF8'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_client = 'UTF8'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'UTF8'");
```

my php form has

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

in database I selected utf-8 general-ci
and it has   ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

But I have this result in database:   artÄ±kolsunbutÃ¼rkÃ§e

How can I solve this problem for new insert?
Thanks

Comment: You have inserted it before.

Comment: Which one I have inserted before?

Comment: Had you inserted this value before you started to use SET NAMES?

Comment: after write these codes I inserted the turkish line input

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`yourtable\`;` please.

Comment: I tried it, What should be the result?  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: I did nearly everthing on google!

Comment: Yes the result is good but it's better if you can put it in the question like you did for the other queries

Comment: So, it might be a file encoding problem. Check with your file editor that your php and js files are not using DOS/ANSI but UTF8 no bom encoding.

Comment: I use cpanel file manager code editor and I select utf-8 as encoding. There is only one choice as utf-8

Comment: What is the original value?

Comment: You use `mysql_connect` to etablish the database connection, right? Not mysqli or PDO, which work with their own connection.

Comment: Yes, show us connection and insert parts of your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)